# Numpy extract submatrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm pretty new in `numpy` and I am having a hard time understanding how to extract from a `np.array` a sub matrix with defined columns and rows:

```
Y = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
```

If I want to extract columns/rows 0 and 3, I should have:

```
[[0 3]
 [12 15]]
```

I tried all the reshape functions...but cannot figure out how to do this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Give  [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) a try:

```
Y[np.ix_([0,3],[0,3])]
```

This returns your desired result:

```
In [25]: Y = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [26]: Y[np.ix_([0,3],[0,3])]
Out[26]:
array([[ 0,  3],
       [12, 15]])
```

Answer (score 22):

One solution is to index the rows/columns by slicing/striding. Here's an example where you are extracting every third column/row from the first to last columns (i.e. the first and fourth columns)

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: Y = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
In [3]: Y[0:4:3, 0:4:3]
Out[1]: array([[ 0,  3],
               [12, 15]])
```

This gives you the output you were looking for.

For more info, check out [this page on indexing in `NumPy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: I like this answer because of the notation's similarity to matlab's notation

Answer (score 12):

```
print y[0:4:3,0:4:3]
```

is the shortest and most appropriate fix .

Answer (score 10):

First of all, your `Y` only has 4 col and rows, so there is no col4 or row4, at most col3 or row3.

To get 0, 3 cols: `Y[[0,3],:]`
To get 0, 3 rows: `Y[:,[0,3]]`

So to get the array you request: `Y[[0,3],:][:,[0,3]]`

Note that if you just `Y[[0,3],[0,3]]` it is equivalent to `[Y[0,0], Y[3,3]]` and the result will be of two elements: `array([ 0, 15])`

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this using:

```
Y[[[0],[3]],[0,3]]
```

which is equivalent to doing this using indexing arrays:

```
idx = np.array((0,3)).reshape(2,1)
Y[idx,idx.T]
```

To make the broadcasting work as desired, you need the non-singleton dimension of your indexing array to be aligned with the axis you're indexing into, e.g. for an n x m 2D subarray:

```
Y[<n x 1 array>,<1 x m array>]
```

This doesn't create an intermediate array, unlike CT Zhu's answer, which creates the intermediate array `Y[(0,3),:]`, then indexes into it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by slicing: `Y[[0,3],:][:,[0,3]]`. More elegantly, it is possible to slice arrays (or even reorder them) by given sets of indices for rows, columns, pages, et cetera:

```py
r=np.array([0,3])
c=np.array([0,3])
print(Y[r,:][:,c]) #>>[[ 0  3][12 15]]
```

for reordering try this:

```py
r=np.array([0,3])
c=np.array([3,0])
print(Y[r,:][:,c])#>>[[ 3  0][15 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting submatrices is possible using two methods, which have already been suggested in the existing answers. Here is a summary using this matrix:

```
Y: array([[4, 1, 4, 3, 1],
          [3, 1, 2, 3, 1],
          [4, 3, 2, 2, 4],
          [2, 4, 3, 2, 3],
          [2, 1, 4, 4, 3]])
```

1. Your submatrix is a contiguous rectangular region of the original matrix, then use regular range indexing. E.g to extract the region at intersection of rows 3,4 and cols 2,3:
   [image]

   ```
   >>> Y[3:, 2:4]
   >>> array([[3, 2],
   >>>        [4, 4]])
   ```
2. You submatrix is not a contiguous region, some rows and/or columns have been removed within this region, then you must build a mesh of valid cells, and use it as a mask. Fortunately this is the purpose of [numpy:ix_](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html), e.g. to extract the intersection of rows 1, 3 and columns 0,3:
   [image]

   ```
   >>> np.ix_((1,3), (0,3))
   >>> (array([[1],
   >>>         [3]]),
   >>>  array([[0, 3]]))
   >>>
   >>> Y[np.ix_((1,3), (0,3))]
   >>> array([[3, 3],
   >>>        [2, 2]])
   ```

Note `np.ix_((1,3), (0,3))` is strictly equivalent to `[[1],[3]],[0, 3]`, so you can use it directly instead of calling the meshgrid builder:

```
>>> Y[[[1],[3]],[0, 3]]
>>> array([[3, 3],
>>>        [2, 2]])
```