# Numpy boolean indexing with multiple dimensions. Why won't it select rows and columns?

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, boolean

I have an `ndarray` with `n>1` dimensions.  I have a boolean array `ok0` corresponding to the rows I want to select, and another boolean array `ok1` corresponding to the columns I want to select.  I want to include all "pages".  So I try `Z[ok0, ok1, :]`, where `ok0` is a 1-D boolean array with `ok0.size == Z.shape[0]`, and `ok1` is a boolean array with `ok1.size == Z.shape[1]`.  Is there a way to use these boolean arrays directly to index my nd-array?

A code fragment paints a thousand words.

```
In [50]: Z = arange(7*8*9).reshape(7, 8, 9)

In [51]: ok0 = Z.sum(1).sum(1)%10<3

In [52]: ok1 = Z.sum(0).sum(1)%10<5

In [53]: ok0.shape
Out[53]: (7,)

In [54]: ok1.shape
Out[54]: (8,)

In [55]: Z[ok0, :, :].shape
Out[55]: (3, 8, 9)

In [56]: Z[:, ok1, :].shape
Out[56]: (7, 4, 9)

In [57]: Z[ok0, ok1, :].shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-ebba5b9a19dd> in <module>()
----> 1 Z[ok0, ok1, :].shape

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

The desired effect can be achieved *indirectly* as follows:

```
In [58]: Z[ok0, :, :][:, ok1, :].shape
Out[58]: (3, 4, 9)
```

If I convert `ok0` and `ok1` from boolean arrays into integer arrays, I can use the solution provided in [this answer to *Selecting specific rows and columns from NumPy array*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22927889/974555):

```
In [88]: ok0i = ok0.nonzero()[0]

In [89]: ok1i = ok1.nonzero()[0]

In [90]: Z[ok0i[:, newaxis], ok1i, :].shape
Out[90]: (3, 4, 9)
```

However, this does not work with the original boolean arrays:

```
In [87]: Z[ok0[:, newaxis], ok1, :].shape
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-7e9fa28c47fa> in <module>()
----> 1 Z[ok0[:, newaxis], ok1, :].shape

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Why does this not work — what's going wrong here?  And (how) can I achieve the desired effect in one go, without repeating my full indexing (which could be potentially long) as I did in command 58?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to select whole rows and columns based on some condition, I think that `np.take` might be an appropriate solution to this problem without having to change the existing method to determining the rows and columns you want, `ok0` and `ok1`.

```
result = np.take(np.take(Z, np.where(ok0)[0], axis=0), np.where(ok1)[0], axis=1)
```

This would first select all of the rows (`axis=0`) where `ok0==True`, and from that subset, select all of the columns (`axis=1`) where `ok1==True`. You need the [0] after the `np.where` since `np.where` outputs a tuple of array(s) (array([]),) containing indices, but you just want the array of indices for `np.take`.

The added advantage to this method is that `np.take` is also much more efficient than using "fancy" indexing of ndarrays.

Comment: `np.where(ok0)[0]` is the same as `ok0.nonzero()[0]`, isn't it?  Although this method works, it doesn't appear more readable than the alternatives I have found that worked (in my present application, efficiency is not an issue as other operations nearby take two orders of magnitude longer).

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Re: do mask selection in one stage:

```
In [152]: result = Z[ok0[:, np.newaxis] & ok1].reshape(ok0.sum(), ok1.sum(),
                                                       *Z.shape[2:])

In [153]: result.shape
Out[153]: (3, 4, 9)

In [154]: (result == Z[ok0][:, ok1]).all()
Out[154]: True
```

Re: long indexing: you can omit any number of trailing dimensions, you can
replace any number of leading dimensions with ellipsis (`...`) provided you
specify all the last dimensions in full.

```
In [155]: Z[0]
Out[155]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71]])

In [156]: Z[...,0]
Out[156]: 
array([[  0,   9,  18,  27,  36,  45,  54,  63],
       [ 72,  81,  90,  99, 108, 117, 126, 135],
       [144, 153, 162, 171, 180, 189, 198, 207],
       [216, 225, 234, 243, 252, 261, 270, 279],
       [288, 297, 306, 315, 324, 333, 342, 351],
       [360, 369, 378, 387, 396, 405, 414, 423],
       [432, 441, 450, 459, 468, 477, 486, 495]])
```

### Description

Mask selection works because we can use high-dim boolean masks to get the elements
that fit the condition:

```
In [157]: arr
Out[157]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [158]: (arr % 2 == 0).astype(int)
Out[158]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])

In [159]: arr[arr % 2 == 0]
Out[159]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

The mask can be generated with broadcasting trick you've used:

```
In [160]: ok0 = arr.sum(1)%10<3

In [161]: ok1 = arr.sum(0)%10<5

In [162]: (ok0[:, np.newaxis] & ok1).astype(int)
Out[162]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])

In [163]: arr[ok0[:, np.newaxis] & ok1]
Out[163]: array([4, 7])
```

But you can notice that the elements are ravelled, count ones in each mask to
restore the shape:

```
In [164]: arr[ok0[:, np.newaxis] & ok1].reshape(ok0.sum(), ok1.sum())
Out[164]: 
array([[4],
       [7]])
```