# How to multiply two matrices vector by vector at specific index in the matrices in pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

Assuming we have two matrices A and B with dim of P * N and N * Q respectively, what is the more efficient way to get values from multiplication of those two matrices only at specific index? For example, vector of row index at {p1,p3,p6,p1,...} in matrix A multiplied by vector of column index at {q2,q5,q2,q3...} in matrix B, and returns scalar values.

There'a another dataframe storing the mapping of those row indexes and column indexes, for example,

```
row,column
p1,q2
p3,q5
p6,q2
p1,q3
...
```

like mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would filter the desired rows and columns out of the matrix (2-D-array). Afterwards you can perform matrix multiplication with the reduced matrices, assigning the resulting vector to scalar variables if you like.

Regarding matrix multiplication, take a look at [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html).

Getting rows and columns from a matrix can be performed in many ways. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927181/selecting-specific-rows-and-columns-from-numpy-array) 
already provides some answers to your problem using [`numpy._ix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) or *broadcasting*.