# Extracting multiple sets of rows/ columns from a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-slicing

I have a 2D numpy array from which I want to extract multiple sets of rows/ columns.

```
# img is 2D array
img = np.arange(25).reshape(5,5)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

I know the syntax to extract one set of row/ column. The following will extract the first 4 rows and the 3rd and 4th column as shown below

```
img[0:4, 2:4]
array([[ 2,  3],
       [ 7,  8],
       [12, 13],
       [17, 18]])
```

However, what is the syntax if I want to extract multiple sets of rows and/or columns? I tried the following but it leads to an `invalid syntax` error

```
img[[0,2:4],2]
```

The output that I am looking for from the above command is

```
array([[ 2],
       [12],
       [17]])
```

I tried searching for this but it only leads to results for one set of rows/ columns or extracting discrete rows/ columns which I know how to do, like using np.ix.

For context, the 2D array that I am actually dealing with has the dimensions ~800X1200, and from this array I want to extract multiple ranges of rows and columns in one go. So something like `img[[0:100, 120:210, 400, 500:600], [1:450, 500:550, 600, 700:950]]`.

Comment: can you provide an explicit minimal example? For instance using `img = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)` as input

Comment: @mozway added a simple example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting specific rows and columns from NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927181/selecting-specific-rows-and-columns-from-numpy-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to generate the indices from the slice:

```
img[np.r_[0,2:4][:,None],2]
```

output:

```
array([[ 2],
       [12],
       [17]])
```

intermediates:

```
np.r_[0,2:4]
# array([0, 2, 3])

np.r_[0,2:4][:,None]  # variant: np.c_[np.r_[0,2:4]]
# array([[0],
#        [2],
#        [3]])
```

Comment: Then how do you select multiple columns in this case?

Comment: There are many possibilities, can you provide an example?

Comment: I know you can use `numpy.ix_` to select multiple rows and columns using: `img[np.ix_([0,2:4], [0,2])]` for example. Is this also possible with `np.ix_`?

Comment: As I said, it depend on exactly the desired output (pairs of coordinates, combinations?) You need to provide an example ;)

Comment: @mozway I have further added some context to the problem, will np.r_ work for multiple groups of rows and columns in one go? Please see the edit that I have just made.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar `img[np.ix_([0,2:4], [0,2])]` gives a syntax error

Comment: @DigvijayRawat - Have you tried to solve your follow up update with the approach in this answer? `img[np.r_[1:3, 4, 2:5][:,None], np.r_[1:3, 0, 2:4]]` obviously works.

Comment: @DigvijayRawat ah sorry, my bad... it doesn't work with `:`, replacing it with a comma works but that's not what was desired

Comment: @mozway for example: get rows 0, 2:4 and columns 0-2, 4, so far you showed how to get multiple rows and a single column

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar what about `img[np.r_[0,2:4][:,None], np.r_[0:2,4]]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your slices with `numpy.r_`:

```
np.r_[0:2, 4]
# array([0,1,4])
```

Then you can get the specific rows and columns as follows:

```
rows = np.r_[0:2, 4]
cols = np.r_[0, 2:4]
img[rows][:, cols]
# array([[ 0,  2,  3],
#       [ 5,  7,  8],
#       [20, 22, 23]])
```