# Standardization or Normalization for selected columns

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, numpy-slicing, standardization

```
**from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train[:,5:7] = sc.fit_transform(X_train[:,5:7])**
```

Here I want to select 5th, 6th and 9th columns.

Is there a way to select the 9th column here??

Comment: hmmm X_train[:,[5,6,8]] ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting specific rows and columns from NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927181/selecting-specific-rows-and-columns-from-numpy-array)

Comment: Also consider a `ColumnTransformer`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select 5th,6th and 9th columns, you can use `.iloc`. Note the column index starts from 0. So, the indices of 5,6, and 9th columns are 4,5 and 8.

```
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train.iloc[:, [4,5,8]] = sc.fit_transform(X_train.iloc[:, [4,5,8]])
```