# Weird Boolean Indexing Output

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, boolean

I'm quite new to Python. I was reading and testing codes in the Numpy official documentation. At the end of part 2.6.2 (Indexing with Boolean Arrays) there's an example that returns a weird answer. Funny though, the documentation says " a weird thing to do".

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
b1 = np.array([False, True, True])
b2 = np.array([True, False, True, False])
a[b1, b2]
```

I think it should return the following answer (or sth like that):

```
array([ 4, 6, 8, 10])
```

but it returns:

```
array([ 4, 10])
```

here is a logic map. Am I wrong somehow?
[Logic Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ht13X.png)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact numpy documentation you're looking at so people can find the relevant section?

Comment: So what DOES it output? I only get errors.

Comment: what's the weird answer?

Comment: I have downloaded the pdf version from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/numpy-user.pdf   , page 23

Comment: It does not return anything. Please correct your code.

Comment: @HesamJokar - I can't find a corresponding example in the official [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) or an explicit explanation for this behavior `a[np.flatnonzero(b1), np.flatnonzero(b2)]` instead of the expectable `a[np.ix_(b1, b2)]`. I think this is a relevant question.

Comment: it's the 'diagonal' of what you expect, `a[[1,2],[0,2]]`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny As you mentioned, this example is not included in the web version. But, ironically, it returns this false answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the docs pointed out, it ***is*** a weird thing to do.

##### In practice, you would use different methods for each of the results that you want.

<sup>(see below)</sup>

As @Michael pointed out in the comments, passing two boolean arrays converts them into index numbers first:

```py
a[b1, b2]

 |
 V

a[np.flatnonzero(b1), np.flatnonzero(b2)]

 |
 V

a[(array([1, 2]), array([0, 2]))]
```

Perhaps it is implemented this way (and not like `a[np.ix_(b1, b2)]`) by the analogy of having only one array for indexing. For example, when you simply do `a[b1]`, this might be happening internally: `a[np.flatnonzero(b1)]`.

And for more than 1 array this is simply the same mechanic.

---

#### 1. To get your expected output:

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22931212/14627505). In your case it would be:

```py
a[b1][:, b2]
```

produces

```py
array([[ 4,  6],
       [ 8, 10]])
```

which you can then [`.flatten()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```py
array([ 4,  6,  8, 10])
```

**Or:**

You can use [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

`np.ix_(b1, b2)` produces a tuple of arrays:

```py
(array([[1],
        [2]]),
 array([[0, 2]]))
```

which can be used to get the same result:

```py
a[np.ix_(b1, b2)].flatten()
```

---

### 2. To get `array([ 4, 10])` in a ***non-weird way***:

Use [integer array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) explicitly:

```py
a[[1, 2], [0, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the returned array seems right. However, the included example remains Weird. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @HesamJokar, in my last example numpy iterates over the corresponding pairs: (1, 0), then (2,2) - thus only 2 elements are selected. This is how integer array indexing works in numpy

Comment: Thanks. Unlike Matlab, it derives X from only the first pair and Y from the second, like the Boolean indexing example. It's odd, but I'm getting used to it. Thanks for the note.

Comment: MATLAB makes selecting the block easy.  The diagonal is harder.  In `numpy` it's the diagonal that's easy.  `ix_` (or equivalent) is needed to get the block,  The docs should make it clear that numpy uses `broadcasting` to pair elements of indexing arrays.