# Numpy: Fancy Indexing over Multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, scientific-computing

Is there an efficient way to index over multiple arrays?

For example, I have an array I want to index from

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

And another array contains the indices.
`b = [[0, 1], [1,2]]`

And I expect `[[1, 2], [5, 6]]`, which indexes the first row of `a` by `[0,1]`, and indexes the second row of `a` by `[1,2]`.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161512/numpy-extract-submatrix is a good duplicate citation for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [107]: a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
In [108]: b = [[0, 1], [1,2]]
```

`a` and `b` are lists.  The appropriate solution is a nested list comprehension

```
In [111]: [[a[i][j] for j in x] for i,x in enumerate(b)]
Out[111]: [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```

Now if `a` is made into a numpy array:

```
In [112]: np.array(a)[np.arange(2)[:,None], b]
Out[112]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

For this the 1st dimension of the array is indexed with a (2,1) array, and the 2nd with a (2,2).  They broadcast together to produce a (2,2) result.

[Numpy extract submatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161512/numpy-extract-submatrix)

is working in  the same direction, but the accepted answer use `ix_`

```
Y[np.ix_([0,3],[0,3])]
```

which won't work in the case of a (2,2) `b`.

```
In [113]: np.array(a)[np.ix_(np.arange(2), b)]
ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional
```

`ix_` will turn the 1st dimension `np.arange(2)` in to the right (2,1).

---

This might make the broadcasting more explicit:

```
In [114]: np.array(a)[[[0,0],[1,1]], [[0,1],[1,2]]]
Out[114]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [5, 6]])
```

It selects elements (0,0), (0,1), (1,1) and (1,2)

---

To further test this, make `b` non symmetic:

```
In [138]: b = [[0, 1,1], [1,2,0]]       # (2,3)
In [139]: np.array(a)[np.arange(2)[:,None], b]
Out[139]: 
array([[1, 2, 2],
       [5, 6, 4]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If `a` and `b` are of same length, may be you can try using `np.take` as following:

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [[0, 1], [1,2]]
result = [np.take(a[i],b[i]).tolist() for i in range(len(a))]

print(result)
# result: [[1, 2], [5, 6]]
```