# Dynamically get submatrix with numpy block(slice) notation

Tags: python, numpy

I want a submatrix from a n-dimensional matrix. Without knowing in advance the dimensionality of the matrix. So given:

```py
import random

a = [10 for _ in range(0, random.randint(0,10))]
M = np.full(a, True)
# Now get the submatrix dynamically with block notation
# so something like:
# str = ["1:5" for _ in range(0, len(a))].join(",")
# N = eval("M[ " + str + "]")
```

I would like to know of a nice way to do this notation wise and also speed wise.

(The other answer supplied in [Numpy extract submatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161512/numpy-extract-submatrix) does not directly solve the question, because the accepted answer, using `.ix_` does not accept a slice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) that uses `slice` notation under the hoods -

```
M[[np.s_[1:5]]*M.ndim]
```

This gives us a `FutureWarning` :

> FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional
>   indexing is deprecated

To avoid it, we need to wrap with with `tuple()`, like so -

```
M[tuple([np.s_[1:5]]*M.ndim)]
```

Using the explicit `slice` notation, it would be -

```
M[tuple([slice(1,5)]*M.ndim)]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the nice stack overflow related search option I have already seen `np.ix_`, [Numpy extract submatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161512/numpy-extract-submatrix), then it would become:

```py
N = M[np.ix_(*[range(1,5) for _ in range(0, len(a))])]
```

Comment: This one throws `ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional` for me.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot the * so the elements of the list are unpacked as arguments for the function, so it becomes: `M[np.ix_(*[[1,5] for _ in range(0, len(a))])]`