# Query about picking values from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have a numpy array of shape (206, 482, 3). I wanted to pick the 1st channel so I used `name_of_array[:][:][0]` but apparently that doesn't select the 1st channel.

I think `name_of_array[:,:,0]` picks the 1st channel. I don't understand why. Why `name_of_array[:][:][0] != name_of_array[:,:,0]`?

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand what each thing does. To do this break up the action left to right. Perhaps rewriting will make this more clear:

```
x[:][:][0] -> ( ( x[:] )[:] )[0]  # Both are valid and equivalent Python syntax
```

So basically, we apply `[:]` to `x`, then `[:]` to the result, then `[0]` to this result. What does `x[:]`? Just return a copy of `x`! Thus

```
( (x[:])[:] )[0] == ( (x)[:] )[0] == (x[:])[0] == x[0]
```

This is of course, not what you expected. On the other hand,

```
x[:, :, 0]
```

returns at once the 0 column of all rows of all frames (I'm treating the index as [frame, row, col]).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: because thats the syntax (see [Numpy basics indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)).

```
arr[:]       == arr # full slice of all dimensions of the array 
arr[:][:]    == arr # full slice of a full slice of all dimensions 
arr[:][:][0] == arr # equal to arr[0] because the first 2 [:] slice all
```

vs

```
arr[:,:,0]  # slice all of 1st dim, slice all of 2nd dim, get 0th of 3rd arr
```

One way to figure things like this out **yourself** is to make a simplified example and *experiment* (heeding [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)):

```
import numpy as np

res = np.arange(4 * 3 * 2).reshape(4,3,2)


print(":,:,:")
print(res[:, :, :])  

print("\n1:2,1:2,:")
print(res[1:2, 1:2, :])

print("\n:,:,0")
print(res[:, :, 0])

print("\n:,:,1")
print(res[:,:,1])
```

Output:

```
# :,:,:   == all of it  
[[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]

[[ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

[[12 13]
  [14 15]
  [16 17]]

[[18 19]
  [20 21]
  [22 23]]]

# 1:2,1:2,:
[[[8 9]]]

# :,:,0
[[ 0  2  4]
[ 6  8 10]
[12 14 16]
[18 20 22]]

# :,:,1
[[ 1  3  5]
[ 7  9 11]
[13 15 17]
[19 21 23]]
```

There are lots of questions about [numpy-slicing](/questions/tagged/numpy-slicing) on SO, some of which are worthwhile studying to advance your knowledge (suggested as probably dupes but they do not address the confusion correctly):

- [Numpy extract submatrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161512/numpy-extract-submatrix)
- [Selecting specific rows and columns from NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927181/selecting-specific-rows-and-columns-from-numpy-array)